# Bottom Sheet Issue

Tags: android

This is what i want to build.
the circular portion will be outside of layout and the rest portion will be transparent as default action

[image]

Till now i have achieved.
the circular portion is getting out but the parent layout is not taking any transparency what i need. I have tried to give the transparent color but its not taking. what i need is the blue portion in the second image, i need it transparent just like when dialog appears. But it is taking the color from parent layout.

[image]
Any reference will be appreciated.TIA

Here is my layout xml :

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:background="@color/colorRed"
    >enter code here
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_45sdp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/firstName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLightGrayText"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="@string/settings"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlackText"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackText"
                       android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/lastName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLightGrayText"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="@string/login_to_access_settings"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
                       android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/userName_Wrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorLightGrayText"
                        android:theme="@style/TextLabelGray"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance_gray">

                        <CustomEditText
                            android:id="@+id/userName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLightGrayText"
                            android:hint="Username"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                       android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/password_wrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorLightGrayText"
                        android:theme="@style/TextLabelGray"
                   app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance_gray">

                        <CustomEditText
                            android:id="@+id/password"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLightGrayText"
                            android:hint="@string/password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                       android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/logInSettingWrapper"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                       android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_rounded_rect"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="@string/login_to_settings"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/cross_pg_bottom_gray" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/nav_settings" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: provide the layout xml file in your question, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make transparent your blue color layout .I hope it helps you unless you update your xml file.

Comment: I have tried giving the transparent color in place of blue but by default its taking the white color as background.